# can't get the same hmac_sha1 results for java and c# (winrt)

Tags: c#, java, cryptography, sha1, hmac

I'm trying to convert a java based code to c# as followed;

The original java code;

```
String str2 = "5f1fa09364a6ae7e35a090b434f182652ab8dd76:{\"expiration\": 1353759442.0991001, \"channel\": \"dreamhacksc2\", \"user_agent\": \".*"

Mac localMac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
localMac.init(new SecretKeySpec("Wd75Yj9sS26Lmhve".getBytes(), localMac.getAlgorithm()));
String str3 = new BigInteger(1, localMac.doFinal(str2.getBytes())).toString(16);
Object[] arrayOfObject2 = new Object[2];
arrayOfObject2[0] = str3;
arrayOfObject2[1] = URLEncoder.encode(str2);
String str4 = String.format("%s:%s", arrayOfObject2);
```

And here is my WinRT based c# code

```
var token="5f1fa09364a6ae7e35a090b434f182652ab8dd76:{\"expiration\": 1353759442.0991001, \"channel\": \"dreamhacksc2\", \"user_agent\": \".*";

var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
var key = encoding.GetBytes("Wd75Yj9sS26Lmhve");
//var key = Convert.FromBase64String("Wd75Yj9sS26Lmhve");

var tokenData = encoding.GetBytes(token);

var result = HmacSha1(key, tokenData);

var hexString = new BigInteger(result).ToString("x");
var urlEncoded = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(token);

var combined = String.Format("{0}:{1}", hexString, urlEncoded);
```

and the hmacsha1 function as I'm running on WinRT;

```
    public static byte[] HmacSha1(byte[] key, byte[] data)
    {
        var crypt = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
        var keyBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(key);
        var cryptKey = crypt.CreateKey(keyBuffer);

        var dataBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(data);
        var signBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.Sign(cryptKey, dataBuffer);

        byte[] result;
        Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(signBuffer, out result);

        return result;
    }
```

So here's the corresponding outpus;

```
(JAVA) 92e893efe72a2f7df6ed409ce35819faba191a63:5f1fa09364a6ae7e35a090b434f182652ab8dd76%3A%7B%22expiration%22%3A+1353759442.0991001%2C+%22channel%22%3A+%22dreamhacksc2%22%2C+%22user_agent%22%3A+%22.*
  (C#) 63b10e1d8e9f99cd7fba2ed46fe8e4a4a40222f5:5f1fa09364a6ae7e35a090b434f182652ab8dd76%3A%7B%22expiration%22%3A+1353759442.0991001%2C+%22channel%22%3A+%22dreamhacksc2%22%2C+%22user_agent%22%3A+%22.*
```

as shown above, the ouputs of HMAC_SHA1 from java and c# are not equal. Any ideas? Am I running encoding problems?

Comment: I would be kind to write a comment if you are down-voting the question.

Comment: For one for not amending your question when it is clear that the C# and Java output may be incorrect. This is a question that is pretty localized. The best way to debug this is to print out all the keys and data using (a better) hexadecimal encoding right before passing it into the HMAC code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep it simple and the code equal.

Java:

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", bytes[i]));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str2 = "5f1fa09364a6ae7e35a090b434f182652ab8dd76:{\"expiration\": 1353759442.0991001, \"channel\": \"dreamhacksc2\", \"user_agent\": \".*";
    Mac localMac;
    try {
        localMac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");

        localMac.init(new SecretKeySpec("Wd75Yj9sS26Lmhve"
                .getBytes("UTF-8"), localMac.getAlgorithm()));
        byte[] result = localMac.doFinal(str2.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String hexString = toHexString(result);
        System.out.println(hexString);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Result:

```
f52202a4a4e4e86fd42eba7fcd999f8e1d0eb163
```

C#:

```
var token = "5f1fa09364a6ae7e35a090b434f182652ab8dd76:{\"expiration\": 1353759442.0991001, \"channel\": \"dreamhacksc2\", \"user_agent\": \".*";

var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
var privateKey = "Wd75Yj9sS26Lmhve";
HMACSHA1 hmac_sha1 = new HMACSHA1(encoding.GetBytes(privateKey));
hmac_sha1.Initialize();
byte[] result = hmac_sha1.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(token));

string hexString = String.Join( "", result.Select( a => a.ToString("x2") ));

Console.WriteLine(hexString);
```

Result:

```
f52202a4a4e4e86fd42eba7fcd999f8e1d0eb163
```

Answer (score 4):

Three tips:

1. When I tested your Java code, I received this value for str3: `f52202a4a4e4e86fd42eba7fcd999f8e1d0eb163` That differs from both Java and C# result posted by you. ([This online tool](http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator) also calculates my result.)
2. Wikipedia contains an [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Examples_of_HMAC_.28MD5.2C_SHA1.2C_SHA256.29), and it seems to be correct based on Java code and online calculator. In the first step, test your Java and C# code with the `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "key", "de7c9b85b8b78aa6bc8a7a36f70a90701c9db4d9"` triplet.
3. It is not a good idea using BigInterger.toString(16) converting byte array to hex string, because when the byte array begins with one ore more zero digit (or hexit?), then the converted hex string will not contains the leading 0 characters.

Comment: you are right, [the code](https://compilr.com/raistlinthewiz/hmac-sha1-test) calculates f52202a4a4e4e86fd42eba7fcd999f8e1d0eb163 as the output.. Will now try to fix my c# code according first.

Comment: and now i'm getting a completely different hash 70F4E22B2600225A3151727323B0CAB40B325045 with [c# code](https://compilr.com/raistlinthewiz/hmac-sha1-csharp-test) that uses .net 4.0's System.Security.Cryptography stuff. I'm completely confused now..

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing bytes with strings. The result of `getBytes()` depends on the default [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding), which may be different from system to system.

Comment: so any ideas on java's default encoding on windows-based hosts?

Comment: @HuseyinUslu it depends on the language settings it seems. In general it is *not* UTF-8 but one of the Windows proprietary schemes that are in turn based on the ISO 8859 standards for 8 bit character encodings. For anything ASCII they - and UTF-8 - should be compatible. Not so much for anything else (inclusing the quite common UTF-16 based schemes).